# Can we do profiling in Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, profiling

I have a JS file contain some configuration code like:

```
module.exports = {
        database: {
            username: 'devusername',
            password: 'devpassword',
            host: 'xx.xx.xx.xx',
            port: 27017,
            name: 'admin'           
        }
};
```

The username,password,host,port and name can be change according to enviornment.
Like **development**, **QA**, **production**.
Every time when I change the environment I need to modify my JS file.Is there any way by which I can keep all the details together and get the values from the respective environment.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can set these settings using environment variables then grab them via [`process.env`](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_env). That way, as long as the environment variables are named the same, it's just a matter of having your environment provisioning setup to provide them.

Comment: Can you please share some example where I can get the complete picture.

Comment: @AnandDeshmukh To expand on what Joseph said, you can do something like `let config = (process.env.NODE_ENV.toLowerCase() === 'dev' ? require('./devConfg') : require('prodConfig')`, obviously this code only allows you to have 2 modes, dev and prod but you could definitely make that a switch or an if or some self contained module. Because this is usually necessary for any project I do, I just use [`node-config`](https://npmjs.com/packages/config) which also allows for host specific configs along with environment based ones.